# CodeIgniter + PagSeguro

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estou com uma certa dificuldade para integrar um sistema com o pagseguro usando codeigniter.

Já fiz o download da biblioteca oficial do pagseguro.
https://pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/guia-de-integracao/tutorial-da-biblioteca-pagseguro-em-php.html

Já criei um controller com todos os dados (no caso para um teste);

```
function pagseguro(){

// $data['dados_pessoa'] = $this->cadastro_model->listar($this->session->userdata('uid'));
// $data['dados_pedido'] = $this->cadastro_model->listarpedidos($this->session->userdata('uid'));


 require_once "PagSeguroLibrary/PagSeguroLibrary.php";

 $paymentRequest = new PagSeguroPaymentRequest();
 $paymentRequest->addItem('12345', 'Software', 1, 50.00);

 $sedexCode = PagSeguroShippingType::getCodeByType('SEDEX');
 $paymentRequest->setShippingType($sedexCode);
 $paymentRequest->setShippingAddress(
    '01452002',  
    'Av. x',  
    '1384',  
    'apto. x',  
    'Jardim x',  
    'São Paulo',  
    'SP',  
    'BRA'
    );
 $paymentRequest->setCurrency("BRL");

 $paymentRequest->setReference('12345');
 $paymentRequest->setRedirectUrl("http://meusite.com.br/pedidos");

 $paymentRequest->addParameter('notificationURL', 'http://www.meusite.com.br/minhapagina');

 try {
    $credentials = PagseguroConfig::getAccountCredentials();
    $checkoutUrl = $paymentRequest->register($credentials);
}
catch (PagseguroServiceException $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}

}
```

É a primeira vez que mexo com o pagseguro em framework e não entendo muito bem.
O controller carrega normalmente e não aparece nenhum erro!
Eu gostaria de saber como faço o post para poder enviar os dados para o pagseguro!

Comment: Seria bom você postar o controller completo aqui. Outro ponto, você já tentou debuggar linha por linha? o controller pode até carregar normalmente, mas não quer dizer que não tem erro.Tente colocar mais informações e se tiver um xdebugger tente debuggar e verifique se está tudo realmente funcionando como deveria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para enviar o post existem 2 métodos:

a função `file_get_contents` *(sim é estranho, eu sei)*, e a função `curl_`.

A função `file_get_contents` envia um POST desde que o segundo parametro seja `false` e o terceiro os dados que você quer enviar, abaixo exemplo:

```
$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
        'var1' => 'some content',
        'var2' => 'doh'
    )
);
$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$result = file_get_contents('http://example.com/submit.php', false, $context);
```

Usando `curl_`:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array('postvar1' => 'value1')));

// recebe a resposta do servidor ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

// processa o resultado ....
if ($server_output == "OK") { ... } else { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Usa esse exemplo que PagSeguro criou em PHP do Checkout transparente. Este exemplo tem como intúito exemplificar as funcionalidades do Checkout transparente e a utilização das funcionalidades JS.

O arquivo esta disponível [neste link].

No exemplo,as suas credenciais devem ser configuradas no arquivo ‘example\\app\\PagSeguroData.class.php’.
O exemplo processa a transação pelo sandbox por default porém você pode alterar o teste para produção passando o parâmetro false na criação do objeto checkout() como, por exemplo, no arquivo example\\checkout.php.

```
<?php
   require "app/Checkout.class.php";
   $checkout = new Checkout(false);
   $checkout->showTemplate();               
?>
```

A senha do arquivo é uol123.

Lembrando que é idela você criar uma conta no sandbox do pagseguro para testar sua aplicação, [Sandbox Pagseguro](https://sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br/#rmcl)

Comment: acredito que você esqueceu de por o link no texto, exatamente nessa parte "O arquivo esta disponível [neste link]."